# Vehicle routing with unit demand

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, discrete-optimization, operations-research

Hi i am looking at a special type of the VRP where the vehicle isn't restricted by the capacity, but can at most visit a given number of costumers $Q$ in a single route. As I see it, it can be be reprecented as a CVRP where the demand for each location is equal to 1 and the capacity of the vehicle is a number $Q$.

My assumption is that the number of routes needed $M$ is equal to, where $N$ is the total number of costumers:

$M = ceil \left(\frac{N}{Q} \right)$

Is this assumtion true, I have not found any litterature on this topic, and can not myself come up with a proof to the statement... Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can model it as demand $1$ and capacity $Q$.  If $M$ is the number of vehicles, then the total capacity is $M Q$, and this must cover the total demand $N$, so $M Q\ge N$, which implies that $M\ge N/Q$. Because $M$ is integer, you can strengthen the lower bound to $M\ge\lceil N/Q\rceil$. Whether this lower bound is attainable depends on the underlying graph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the case of weather the bound is attainable is what I was most curious about. My thought was that the unit demand could maybe ensure that the bound is attainable, but I am not able to find any proof of this.

Comment: Is your graph complete?

Comment: Ohh sorry yeah that is an information I forgot to mention, but yes it is a complete symmetric graph, where the triangular inequality is valid.

Comment: Then, yes, the lower bound is attainable.  Note that it still might be cheaper to use more vehicles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was also what my logic was telling me. There are no cost to the vehicles in my problem, so if i'm not mistaken, it can only at best give the same cost (travel distance) to use an extra vehicle.

Comment: Consider $N=6$ and $Q=3$, with the customers geographically clustered in pairs.  It can be cheaper to use $3$ vehicles instead of $2$.

Comment: I had not thought about that example, but that is very true! thank you so much for the help on this question!